# how subsribe ionic2 event

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic2

In normal case, when I want to observe some event, I should write something like

```
constructor(el: ElementRef) {
  this.el = el.nativeElement;
  let source = Observable.fromEvent(
    this.el,
    'touchmove',
    (event) => {
      return { event};
    });
  this.panMove$ = source.subscribe((event)=>{
    console.log(event);
  });
}
```

How can I make Observable for Ionic2 gest like pan.
I use in template

```
(pan)="pan($event)"
```

but unfortunately it generates some problems in my code

Comment: Lets say Page1.html has your pan event code set up. Do you just want to handle the pan event in the Page1.ts file? or are you trying to achieve something different?

Comment: I want handle event Page1.ts. I need sonthink like Observable.fromEvent because I want add some logic with I need counting the pan event  and make some relation with  transitionend event

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can't have access to underlying observables involved for declarative event bindings in Angular2.

There is an open issue for this:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4062